# newbie for rspec,expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    card_no '6217920016000864'

    factory :invalid_card do
      card_no nil
    end
  end
end
```

**card_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe CardsController do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'assigns card' do
      card = create(:card)
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:card)).to eq([card])
    end

    it 'show index' do
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
  end
end
```

**cards_controller.rb**

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user.login_name=="admin"
      #admin
      @cardlist = set_paginate Card
    else
      #普通管理员
      @restaurant_ids = Restaurant.where('parent_id = ? or id = ?', current_user.restaurant.id, current_user.restaurant.id).collect { |r| r.id }
      @cardlist = set_paginate Card.where('restaurant_id in (?) ', @restaurant_ids)
    end
  end
end
```

two errors like this `expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"">` and `expect(assigns(:card)).to eq([card]) got nil`.

help me thanks!

Comment: please fix the formatting and include part of the controller you have

Comment: It seems your `index` action does not work as you expect. You should post the code of your `CardsController#index` action if you expect people to comment on it.

Comment: Yes, please share your controller code.  Also testing for a single card in the index action is not normal; index would normally be a list of cards (`@cards`).  A single card `@card` is what you would expect in the show action.

Comment: in `spec_helper.rb` have this setting  `config.render_views`?

Answer (score 2):

**First test** is for what data controller provides to the view. Looking on the controller you have you should check for `assigns(:cartdlist)` I think. And use `match_array` rather than `eq`.

**Second test** doesn't render anything as it doesn't go anywhere (your `get` is just for the first `it` block). So try this:

```
describe CardsController do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    before do
      card = create(:card)
      get :index
    end

    it 'assigns card' do
      expect(assigns(:cardlist)).to match_array([card])
    end

    it 'show index' do
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
  end
end
```

It's probably not the problem in your case as you got different error but to allow expect syntax your spec_helper.rb file should contain:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # most omitted ... 
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
end
```

or 
`c.syntax = [:should, :expect]`
for both

Comment: yes,i don't understand the first it too.because i follow the book rspec.i delete the first it.and only test second.but i found that expect(response).to render_template(:index) always got wrong,but response.should render_template(:index) is success.why?

Comment: I updated my answer, so check it. And you can even omit `before` block there and put `get` into `expect` that way: `it { expect(get :index).to render_tamplate :index` but for now leave it as it is in the answer

Answer (score 1):

This

```
expect(assigns(:card)).to eq([card]) got nil
```

because I believe you assign data to `cards` (after updating question: `cardlist`)

This

```
expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"">
```

because you don't call `get :index` in test

Comment: i change my code and delete first it.but if i write response.should render_template(:index) and it works,but expect(response).to render_template :index didn't work.do you know why?